# How to select all visible elements from list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all visible elements from list, but I can't find the way.

I have list

```
<ul id="posts">
     <li style="display:none">1</li>
     <li style="display:none">2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li style="display:none">4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li style="display:none">6</li>
     <li>7</li>
     <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to get every second visible element and add class "visible" to it.

I want this result

```
<ul id="posts">
     <li style="display:none">1</li>
     <li style="display:none">2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li style="display:none">4</li>
     <li class="visible">5</li>
     <li style="display:none">6</li>
     <li>7</li>
     <li class="visible">8</li>
</ul>
```

I tried something like this

```
var jQuerylistItems = jQuery('#posts').children('li');
jQuerylistItems.filter(':visible').addClass('visible');
```

and it works, but not right, somethimes add class, sometimes not, I'm not sure why.

Can somebody help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like the following:

```
jQuery('#posts > li:visible:odd').addClass('visible');
```

Checkout out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amxkw0yy/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution for you. And [also demo on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6q50qgtq/)

```
(function() {
'use-strict';

var el = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++) {
    if(!el[i].style.display && i%2 !== 0) {
            el[i].className = 'visible';
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try **.each();**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul > li').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $(this).addClass('visible');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ejqr2gum/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5op0wzv9/.

```
$('ul > li:visible').each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass(index % 2 === 1 ? "visible" : "");
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not see the "every second element" part.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `addClass()` to use a callback and the first argument of callback is index

```
jQuerylistItems.filter(':visible').addClass(function(i) {    
    return i % 2 == 1 ? 'visible' : null;
});
```

My understanding is only add this class to every other visible element.

You will also need to remove this class before running it again which could be the part of the problem you are encountering

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8mv6mpd/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you want, but here you go!!. Hope it helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> MY TEST </title>
        <meta charset = 'utf-8'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="posts">
            <li style="display:none">1</li>
            <li style="display:none">2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li style="display:none">4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li style="display:none">6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var visibleElements = [];
            var allListElements = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); // Get the reference to al the "li" elements
            var index;

            // Check for each element in array if his display its diferent to "none", if true, add that element to the array "visibleElements"
            for (index = 0; index < allListElements.length; index++){
                if(allListElements[index].style.display != 'none'){ 
                    visibleElements.push(allListElements[index]);
                }
            };

            //Adding the class
            for (var index2 in visibleElements){
                visibleElements[index2].className = 'visible';
                console.log('VISIBLE') // Check if adding the class name is working, if console shows 4 "VISIBLE" then its OK.
            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```